# Python IRC Bot silent timeout(?) - Stops working suddenly

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I recently started writing my own IRC Bot, nothing fancy, just reads a channel and posts contents of a text file for specific commands.

```
# let's connect
irc_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc_socket.connect((server, 6667))

# now we login and send a test message
irc_socket.send(str.encode('PASS ' + pw + '\r\n'))
irc_socket.send(str.encode('NICK ' + bot + '\r\n'))
irc_socket.send(str.encode('USER ' + bot + '\r\n'))
irc_socket.send(str.encode('JOIN #' + channel + '\r\n'))

while 1:
    text = irc_socket.recv(2040).decode()
    if text.startswith('!ideen'):
        do stuff #lot of code, shouldn't be of importance
```

The weird thing is that everything works as I want it to, but for some reasons it stops working after some time. It doesn't timeout or give any errors, it just stops reacting at all. First I thought it gets overload by too many messages, but it also happens if the channel simply stays empty for 20 mins or so. Happens the same, when I run it from Pycharm or the command line (not sure why it'd make a difference).

I'm probably not the only one with the problem, but I couldn't find anything. Thank you for your help, even hints for how to debug something like this.

The IRC Channel is a Twitch-IRC Chat if that is of any importance.

Edit: Tried @matt-m hint for debugging, it seems he stops getting the messages. The text-messages always are empty strings.

Comment: Wait for it to 'freeze' then pause in the debugger to see what line it's stuck on. My guess is something weird is going on with  `irc_socket.recv(2040).decode()`

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you perhaps not responding to a server `PING` with a `PONG`?

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2812#section-3.7.2

> If a connection fails to respond to a PING
> message within a set amount of time, that connection is closed.

So you should make sure you do that. I thought that it would raise some socket error when the connection closes, but according to [How to tell if a connection is dead in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667640/how-to-tell-if-a-connection-is-dead-in-python), that might not always be the case.

Comment: Thank you, I saw some Pings coming from the server, but did not realize that I'd need to respond to them. I'll try this tomorrow and give feedback!

Comment: This worked out perfectly, ran for over two hours without problems. Thanks again!